How can I separate two items vertically without affecting the height of the first one
as the title states, I would like to separate the logoSlogan and the stats div vertically, however, if I put some margin in between them, it moves the both of them. Is there any clue on how I could make some "space" in between them so they're not clustered?


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(90.6deg, rgb(59, 158, 255) -1.2%, rgb(246, 135, 255) 91.6%);
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logoSlogan {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.stats {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
<body>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="logoSlogan">
      <img src="media/CL_Logo_Blue_Hex/CL_Logo_HD_White.png" class="CL_Logo">
      <h1>Amogus</h1>
      <p>This is a simple landing page with a gradient background.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="stats aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-up">
      <h1> Check out these cool stats!</h1>
      <p> Total Videogames: 100.000 </p>
      <p> Total Critics: 100 </p>
      <p> Total Critiques: 5.000 </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>




margin-bottom on the logo element?

if I put some margin in between them, it moves the both of them - that's because the body has display: flex; align-items: center; whenever you add vertical space or you add other elements, the center point will be changed, thus, all the underlying elements will be moved to match the new center point. to understand what I mean, remove display: flex from body then add margin-bottom: 10px to logo-slogan and increase it to see that only stats div is moving down. To make it clear, this is normal behavior for flex and you can't change it unless you remove flex prop.

@MHDAlaaAlhaj that was exactly what was bothering me, thank you!

use justify content: space-between, space-around or space-evenly to put automatic spacing between the flex items, or use gap:100px to get fixed spacing


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(90.6deg, rgb(59, 158, 255) -1.2%, rgb(246, 135, 255) 91.6%);
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction:column;
min-height:700px;
}



.logoSlogan {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.stats {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
<body>


    <div class="logoSlogan">
      <img src="media/CL_Logo_Blue_Hex/CL_Logo_HD_White.png" class="CL_Logo">
      <h1>Amogus</h1>
      <p>This is a simple landing page with a gradient background.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="stats aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-up">
      <h1> Check out these cool stats!</h1>
      <p> Total Videogames: 100.000 </p>
      <p> Total Critics: 100 </p>
      <p> Total Critiques: 5.000 </p>
    </div>


</body>




Add this CSS to your style
.content {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 gap: 10px;
}

